# How many girls have black hair?

Tags: combinatorics

We have a group of $57$ peoples. $35$ of them are girls. $30$ of them have black hair. How many girls, at least, have black hair?

I have immediately thought to the principle of inclusion-exclusion to answer but first I did very simple reasoning but I do not know if it is correct. Since we don't want to know the exact number of girls: $52$ peoples $-$ $35$ girls = $22$ boys. In the worst case, all the boys have black hair, but since there are only $22$ of them, $13$ girls are left with black hair. Can such an answer be reasonable? If it's wrong, why?

Comment: You meant to write $\color{red}{57}$ people - $35$ girls $= 22$ boys.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct but you made an error.

There are $30$ persons with black hair, so if $22$ of them are boys then $30-22=8$ girls have black hair.

So not $35-22$ as you reasoned wrongly.

Comment: Yes, you are right :) So, despite my error, could it be a good answer in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, it is a good answer and PIE is not needed.